# Failed to start X server

Tags: opensuse, x-server, display-manager

My system is OpenSUSE Leap

I had a problem with HDD that lead to the system not booting. After fixing that and fixing the boot loader I ended up with a failed to start X server.

At boot time I got:

```
failed to start X display manager
```

And the booting process stops at:

```
Reached target graphical interface
```

I can log to the terminal with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
From terminal `startx` shows:

```
There is no link / var / lib / X11 / X to the correct X server binary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple reinstallation of the Xorg packages will solve the problem.

In openSUSE :

> zypper in -f xorg-x11*